# GET calls to WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem with an XML response to a call to the Web API.
Specifically, I have a function "GetValue" call that when I should return in XML format based to the id or class "Cellulare" or class "Televisore".

The problem is that if I make a request from browser gives me the following error:

```
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
```

This is the example:

```
Public Class Cellulare
    Public Property Colore As String
    Public Property SistemaOperativo As String
End Class

Public Class Televisore
    Public Property Colore As String
    Public Property Marca As String
End Class          

Public Function GetValue(ByVal id As Integer) // ' As Cellulare
    If Id = 1 Then    
        Dim MyTelevisore As New Televisore    
        MyTelevisore.Colore = "grigio"
        MyTelevisore.Marca = "lg"
        Return MyTelevisore
    Else            
        Dim MyCellulare As New Cellulare    
        MyCellulare.Colore = "nero"
        MyCellulare.SistemaOperativo = "android"    
        Return MyCellulare
    End If    
End Function
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem???

Thank in advance
greetings
Donato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is wrong.

You have simple objects to return, that can be handled easily by the default serializers webapi has to offer.

Your returned object type should be `IHttpActionResult` (webapi2) or `HttpResponseMessage`.

I would NOT go for what @Frank Witte suggested, cause returning the object itself is bad practice. Specifically here you can just return a generic object through `IHttpActionResult` / `HttpResponseMessage`.

You should do something like:

```
Public Function GetValue(ByVal id As Integer) As IHttpActionResult
    If Id = 1 Then    
        Dim MyTelevisore As New Televisore    
        MyTelevisore.Colore = "grigio"
        MyTelevisore.Marca = "lg"
        Return Ok(MyTelevisore)
    Else            
        Dim MyCellulare As New Cellulare    
        MyCellulare.Colore = "nero"
        MyCellulare.SistemaOperativo = "android"    
        Return Ok(MyCellulare)
    End If    
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. This is what I wanted. I tried the example that you have suggested and it works.

Comment: This warning appears: Vote Up requires 15 reputation! I have 6 reputation.

Answer (score -1):

It throws the error because you do not supply any return type to your GetValue function. You commented that out.

As I can tell from your code you are returning a different type of object depending on the id you supply to the GetValue call. I do not know the complete context of what you are trying to do, but from what I can see it would make more sense to have a different controller, or route at least, for the different types of object:

```
/api/cellulare/<id>
```

Would map to a controller CellulareController.

```
/api/televisore/<id>
```

Would map to a controller TelevisoreController. Each with their own Get(), Post() and Delete() methods if you will.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you sure that's the reason?

Comment: You can test it by explicitly setting a return type for your function.

Comment: I think that approach is bad practice. Some generic object should be returned such as `IHttpActionResult` / `HttpResponseMessage`.

Comment: Yes, that is even better. My point is that you do not define a return type at all, and that does not serialize well in XML. Hence the error message.

Comment: Ok, maybe you're technically right, but I think @BlackThunder needs a more constructing answer here...

Comment: @ilanS You are right. My answer was not complete. +1 for yours.

Comment: OK... sorry for down-voting you. I regret it now :) but the site won't let me up vote it again..