# consuming REST service, method returning multiple types .. what to do

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am consuming someone elses REST service for my app. the problem is that each request can return 1 of 3 different types when responding
either:

1. the expected successfull response type
2. an error response which wraps the 500 (`Error`)
3. a validation error response (`ValidationErrors`)

I am currently calling the service wrapping each request with a class like this:

```
public class ApiResponse<T>
{
    public T ResponseObject { get; set; }
    public ValidationErrors<ValidationError> Errors { get; set; }
    public Error Error { get; set; }
}



 public async Task<ApiResponse<AMethodResponse>> AMethod(AMethodRequest req)
    {
        ApiResponse<AMethodResponse> resp = new ApiResponse<AMethodResponse> { Errors = new ValidationErrors<ValidationError>() };
        using (HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.Create(new AuthorisationHandler(), new ContentTypeHandler()))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseURI);

            var httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsXmlAsync<AMethodRequest>("AMethod/", req);
            if (!httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
//its at this point that I need to work out if i am getting Validation Errors or.. a plain Error
//I can do this, but of course if its a plain error it will fall over
                resp.Errors = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<ValidationErrors<ValidationError>>();
            }
            else
            {
                resp.ResponseObject = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<AMethodResponse>();
            }
        }
        return resp;
    }
```

I wonder if there is a more reliable pattern to writing consuming methods.

thanks

Comment: Does the REST service provide a different status code for each eventuality?  It looks like it gives 500 for the error, but does it give a 200 both success *and* validation errors?  If so, you can use `httpResponseMessage.StatusCode` directly (rather than simple `IsSuccessStatusCode`).  If it is 200 in both cases (a fault in the REST service!) then you can use `ReadAsStringAsync()` then have your code inspect the serialized string to check if it's a validation error, then deserialise manually once you know the type.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, totally didn't think of that. yes it gives a 200 for all is well. 400 for validationerror and 500 for a real error.. I'll re-jig it. out of interest does the code look about right as is (ignoring the problem the question is about)

Comment: Maybe my answer here can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30370604/get-calls-to-webapi/30424749#30424749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it gives a 200 for all is well. 400 for validationerror and 500 for a real error

Check the status code directly, rather than use `IsSuccessStatusCode` :

```
var httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsXmlAsync<AMethodRequest>("AMethod/", req);

switch (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode)
{
    case HttpStatusCode.OK:  //200
        resp.ResponseObject = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<AMethodResponse>();
        break;

    case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:  //400
        resp.Errors = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<ValidationErrors<ValidationError>>();
        break;

    case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:  //500
        throw new Exception("failed");  // use appropriate exception and/or read 500 wrapper
        break;
}

return resp;
```